# How to replace a value within <script> tag with HTML parser?

Tags: java, html-parsing, html-parser

I have following function in JS:

```
function replaceSrcc() {

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = DataVideo;
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem);
}
```

I am trying to replace the keyword `DataVideo` by the other value `videoID` by using HTML parser in Java:

```
if(tag instanceof ScriptTag){
      if("DataVideo".equals(tag.getAttribute("copy.src"))){
           tag.setAttribute("copy.src", videoID);
       }
};
```

This however, does not work. I assume I have a mistake in finding the `copy.src` element within `<script>` tag, I think it is not an attribute, but I do not know exactly how to find it.¨

---

EDIT: the whole class that is in charge of parsin HTML, MyNodeVisitor, looks like this:

```
public class MyNodeVisitor extends NodeVisitor {
        String name;
        String text;
        String storyText;
        String videoID;
        ArrayList<String> pictures;


        public MyNodeVisitor() {

        }

        public MyNodeVisitor(ArrayList<String> Pictures, String Name, String Text, String StoryText, String VideoId){
            this.name = Name;
            this.text = Text;
            this.storyText = StoryText;
            this.videoID = VideoId;
            this.pictures = Pictures;
        }

        public void visitStringNode (Text string)
        {
            if (string.getText().equals("DataName")) {
                string.setText(name);
            }

            else if (string.getText().equals("DataText")){
                  string.setText(text);
            }

            else if (string.getText().equals("DataStory")){
                  string.setText(storyText);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void visitTag (Tag tag)
        {
            if(tag instanceof ImageTag){
                if("DataIcon".equals(tag.getAttribute("src"))){
                    tag.setAttribute("src", pictures.get(0));
                }
                else if("DataIcon2".equals(tag.getAttribute("src"))){
                    tag.setAttribute("src", pictures.get(1));
                }
                else if("DataIcon3".equals(tag.getAttribute("src"))){
                    tag.setAttribute("src", pictures.get(2));
                }
                else if("DataIcon4".equals(tag.getAttribute("src"))){
                    tag.setAttribute("src", pictures.get(3));
                }
                else if("DataIcon5".equals(tag.getAttribute("src"))){
                    tag.setAttribute("src", pictures.get(4));
                }
            }
            else if(tag instanceof ScriptTag){
                if(((ScriptTag) tag).getStringText().contains("DataVideo")){
                    String tagText = ((ScriptTag)tag).getStringText();
                    //String tagText = tagText.replaceAll("DataVideo",videoID);
                    }


                    /*NodeList nodes = ((ScriptTag)tag).getChildren();
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){
                        if (nodes.elementAt(i).getText().equals("DataVideo")){
                            nodes.elementAt(i).setText(videoID);*/
                        }

                    }
      }
```

### }

EDIT:
Here is the pre-prepared HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>

 ....

</head>
<body>

<script>
function replaceSrcc() {

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = DataVideo;
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem);
    } 


    if (window.addEventListener){
         window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrcc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', replaceSrcc);
    }

</script>

<h1 align="center">DataName</h1>

<div class="tabber">



     <div class="tabbertab" bgcolor="blue">
      <h2 color="red">Info </h2>
      <p>DataText</p>
     </div>

     <div class="tabbertab">
      <h2>Story from TIME</h2>
      <p>DataStory</p>
     </div> 

     <div class="tabbertab">
      <h2>Pictures</h2>
        <div id="album">
            <ul class="gallery">
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">1<img src=DataIcon alt="landscape image 1" title="landscape image 1" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">2<img src=DataIcon2 alt="landscape image 2" title="landscape image 2" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">3<img src=DataIcon3 alt="portrait image 1" title="portrait image 1" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">4<img src=DataIcon4 alt="portrait image 2" title="portrait image 2" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">5<img src=DataIcon5 alt="landscape image 3" title="landscape image 3" /></a></li>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>   
     </div>

     <div class="tabbertab">
      <h2>Video</h2>

        <object width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src=DataVideo type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
    </object>
           </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose you are using `org.htmlparser.*` library. It would be helpful, if you posted more of your java code. However, it seems, that you want to parse HTML dynamically generated by JavaScript. AFAIK, htmlparser can't do that. You will need some type of screen scraping library to be able to render JavaScript in HTML documents.

Comment: Yes, I am using org.htmlparser library. What I am trying to do is to parse HTML and replace the keyword "DataVideo" in the JavaScript function by a string videoID representing the youtube link. Once this is done, the function replaceSrcc() will recreate embed object with a newly set src attribute. So you think this is not gonna work? I will put the whole  htmlparser class in the edit of the question.

Comment: Please provide your HTML too. Where does the HTML come from? I also don't quite get how you plan to inject your JS function with htmlparser and why you are using the combination of both. Please elaborate on your scenario!

Comment: The point is I am accessing the data from the database into my Java application and then I have to submit this retrieved value to HTML and  create it based on those values. To parse those values to HTML, I am using htmlparser. It worked perfectly, except for one value, which is described here. The problem is I did not figure out how to replace a value within OBJECT element with a use of html parser, so instead, I created JS function to do that and now I want to pass that value to JS function and this function will then replace this value onload. Kind of creepy, but the only solution.

Comment: So you retrieve actual HTML from a DB, parse it, inject JS and then what?

Comment: I do not retrieve the whole HTML (if you mean that). I just retrieve the value, concretely youtube link, which will be parsed to JS function, which cause the change in my pre-prepared HTML template (see edit).

Comment: I posted the HTML in the edit, I hope it is clear now. If not I can provide more of the code.

Comment: Okay, two new questions: 1. Is your template notation (e.g. `src=DataIcon2`) some kind of standardized syntax? 2. Why are you testing `tag.getStringText()` for "DataVideo"? The [docs](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/tags/CompositeTag.html#getStringText()) say: _Return the text between the start tag and the end tag._ Sounds to me, like it doesn't include your `src` attribute. Did you have a look at what `getStringText()` returns?

Comment: Answers: 1. it is not standardized, I just made it like this. I am not an expert in HTMl at all, so I found it useful and it worked. 2. I know what getStringText() does and I think it is what I need, once I get the content between script tags, I can replace the value DataVideo by the value retrieved from database, but this is not working.

Comment: I believe it's not working because `getStringText()` only retrieves the tag's inner HTML and leaves out its attributes. Did you check that? Also: Are you positive, that an `<embed>` is a type of ScriptTag? Otherwise it won't be found by your code. You could try to debug and see where it goes wrong.